# componentDidMount is not updating my state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am new to react,I just making a view counter for various divs.For that I need the height of the div and scrollTop height.But after getting that Values I have to setstate the values.But it is not working.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var NewsDetail = require('./news-details');
var $ = require('jquery');
module.exports = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function() {
        return {
          news: [{
            id: "5",
            data: "I probably am using the wrong I probably am using the wrong terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value for each key and a value for each key's object. S"
          }, {
            id: "6",
            data: "I probably am using the wrong I probably am using the wrong terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value I probably am using the wrong terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value I probably am using the wrong terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value for each key and a value for each key's object. S"
          }, {
            id: "7",
            data: "I probably am using the wrong terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value I probably am using the wrong terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value I probably am using the wrong terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value for each key and a value for each key's object. S"
          }, {
            id: "8",
            data: "I probably am using the wrong I probably am using the wrong terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value for each key and a value for each key's object. S"
          }, {
            id: "9",
            data: "I probably am using the wrong I probably am using the wrong terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value I probably am using the wrong terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value I probably am using the wrong terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value for each key and a value for each key's object. S"
          }, ],
          length: null,
          height: 0
        }
      },
      componentWillMount: function() {},
      componentDidMount: function() {

        console.log(this.state.length)
        var lengthh = document.getElementById('newscontanier').children.length;
        console.log(lengthh);
        if(lengthh != this.state.length) {
          this.setState({
            length: lengthh //Still  null
          })
        }
      },
      render: function() {
        var newsdata = this.state.news.map(function(newss) {
            return( < NewsDetail key = {
                newss.id
              } {...newss
              }
              />)
            });
          return(<div className="newscontanier" id="newscontanier">{newsdata}</div>)
        }
      })
```

Comment: I'd recommend learning a bit on naming your variables. Looking at your code it's **very** hard to find out what's going on and whether something is a typo or intentional.

Comment: Sorry sir I am new to programming.The code Actually render divs correctly.But the state is not updating.

Comment: Have you checked if `lengthh != this.state.length` condition holds true? `lengthh` variable could be `undefined` and as the condition uses the non strict equals  operator (if used `null == undefined // true` ) so `setState` won't get called at all

Answer (score 0):

You just have a syntax error here, remove the single quotes around the jsx -

```
 return (
    <div className="newscontanier" id="newscontanier">{newsdata}</div>
 );
```

see working copy here - https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/54531/

Comment: Sorry sir I didn't made that mistake.Somehow i changed that when I posting in StackOverflow.In my actual code there will be no quotes.But still I can't Update my state

Comment: @Nane then I don't see where the problem is? if you just look at `document.getElementById('newscontanier').children` you have all those div items and their information is on there? If you look at the fiddle provided, your state is updating to 5 right now. Your overall question is kind of unclear. I also don't know why you're looking at `state.length`, did you mean `state.news.length`???